# PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Twilio\TwiML' not found in

Tags: php, twilio, fatal-error

i got this error.

I composer the Twilio SDK in my centos 7 server.

This is my code of my error php file

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Twilio\TwiML;

// Start our TwiML response
$response = new TwiML;

// Read a message aloud to the caller
$response->say(
    "Thank you for calling! Have a great day.",
    array("voice" => "alice")
);

echo $response;
```

what can I do??

Comment: Can you confirm that you see a `vendor` folder that includes the Twilio library? It looks like you're maybe missing the installed library.

Answer (score 9):

The class is called `Twilio\Twiml`.

On linux the file will not be found if the case is not correct.

Comment: The class is `Twilio\TwiML`. It's here: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/master/Twilio/TwiML/TwiML.php

Comment: But this is an abstract class, may you need this: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/master/Twilio/Twiml.php?  
of your class the class name is Twilio\TwiML\TwiML (namepace + classname)

Comment: Using Twilio\Twiml worked for me.

There is also a Twilio\TwiML folder which has certain classes.

I guessMaybe the Twilio documentation needs to be updated to use the correct name of the class (as per the filename).

Answer (score 5):

If anyone runs into this issue... The normal Twiml class has been deprecated: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/pull/498/commits/64227acd17dd76bcaea0d94ccb930d571d4c2b67

It took me a moment to understand what was going on here, and it's pretty irritating that their documentation hasn't been updated to resolve this.   Or maybe it was, but I don't see it, and as of this writing, their examples still reference deprecated examples.

Twilio\TwiML is now an abstract and extended by the classes that you would start using instead of the old Twiml.

For example:

```
$s = new Twilio\VoiceResponse; // also you can use Messaging or Fax
$s->say('Hello World');
echo $s;
```

refer to /vendor/twilio/sdk/Twilio/TwiML/{Type}Response.php

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, I tested myself referencing this code sample:
https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/api-snippets/blob/master/guides/voice/respond-incoming-calls-guide/respond-no-parameters/example.5.x.php

Make sure you have the latest PHP SDK package in Composer or include it correctly, my hunch is this is the root of your error.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the documentation needs to be updated or the code needs to be modified.
The Class TwiML is abstract and the Twiml class is the one that needs to be used instead. The VoiceResponse class can also be used.

The only issue is the location of the use statements on version 5.x:

use Twilio\TwiML\VoiceResponse;
use Twilio\Twiml;

Answer (score 0):

```
use Twilio\TwiML\MessagingResponse;

$response = new MessagingResponse();
```

1) if you are working for messaging this code will work
or if you work for voice response then use VoiceResponse instead of MessagingResponse.

2) this will work and make sure you have installed proper library for it.